# "had initially" vs. "initially had"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, word-order, adverb-position

As in:

> I **initially had** planned to cite my sources.

Rather than:

> I **had initially** planned to cite my sources.

Comment: The second one sounds better to me but my grammar sense tells me the first one is correct.

Comment: Words in a sentence/ clause can be moved around to shift the focus (emphasis) as in this example. Also, "**Initially,** I had planned to cite my sources;" "I had planned **initially** to cite my sources." None ungrammatical, better or superior. However, each conveys a subtly different message.

Comment: There are possibly some previous posts dealing with this issue. Check.

Comment: Thank you, I think I am too new to upvote on this stack exchange but I value your comment nonetheless!

Comment: Nice to be help. Keep coming back, Turner. See also: [ell.se]

Comment: Though according to CGEL (about adjunct / adverb placement) 'There is a great deal of variation in use, and features of context, style, prosody and euphony play a role in some decisions' [quoting selectively], there are _some_ restrictions. However, placement of many adverbs _is_ often a matter of choice. Of the 8 possible slots for 'initially' here, only 1 doesn't work. 'to initially cite' transfers modification to 'cite'. Commas might be preferred with some options. I'd say 'initially' after 'had' sounds more idiomatic; if stress is wanted to fall on 'initially', fronting it works best.

Comment: If this is for an academic paper, I hope the sentence doesn't continue “… but I have now decided not to”, ’cause that would be quite bad, regardless of where you put the modifiers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does adverb placement affect meaning?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83399/does-adverb-placement-affect-meaning)

Answer (score 2):

For a very simple reason, the second example

- *I had initially planned to cite my sources*

is to be preferred to the first example

- *I initially had planned to cite my sources*.

Both sentences are grammatical, but the second allows contraction, and would be **pronounced**

- *I'd initially planned to cite my sources*

which is better colloquial English. Contractions are almost obligatory in colloquial English.

It's also true that if there is a focussed adverb in a sentence (there may be several, after all), 
the best place to put it is right after the first auxiliary verb, where negation and other heavy stuff tends to work best.

Answer (score -1):

My answer: It is better to avoid splitting the two parts of the verb, but I would ask one more question: What does that adverb contribute? Does "I had planned to cite my sources ... " deliver the same message? How does "initially" make the message more clear? My question dodges yours, but we we all tend to clutter our writing with distracting words. We filter them out in normal conversation. If we'd edit them out of our writing, we might not have to fret over the placement of a modifier.

Comment: Why is it "better to avoid splitting the two parts of the verb"? Is there a rule someplace about this? Where did you find it?

Comment: No doubt some writers (and speakers) use "initially planned" to mean simply "planned," in which case your criticism about cluttering is valid; but in many other instances, an original plan undergoes changes prior to execution, in which case "initially planned" (or something like it) is crucial to the accuracy of the description.