# Can changing the position of a frequency adverb from the start to the middle part affect meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-order, adverb-position

Many frequency adverbs can be placed at the start, in the middle or at the ending of a sentence.

In [Does adverb placement affect meaning?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83399/does-adverb-placement-affect-meaning), in the answer https://english.stackexchange.com/a/83402/16498 is analyzed the difference between the end placement and others. But what is the difference between the start and middle placement?

Does this placement make any difference to the meaning?

> Sometimes I go running.
> I sometimes go running.
> I go running sometimes.

Do those sentences mean the same or not? If not, is there any difference in feeling, mood or something else? Is there some context in which they have different use?

Comment: Closely related if arguably not quite a duplicate:
 [Does adverb placement affect meaning?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83399/does-adverb-placement-affect-meaning)

Comment: Placing a word at the start (or end) adds emphasis. If you're emphasising "sometimes", e.g. as part of a comparison or contrast, you may put it at the start, e.g. "sometimes I walk, sometimes I fly" (contrasting the two options) or "sometimes I fly, but I always travel light" (emphasising that flying is occasional but travelling light is constant). This doesn't really change the meaning, just the emphasis.

Comment: @StuartF Thank you. Why you haven't put it as an answer? It is one.

Comment: The paper to which John Lawler links discusses all possible positions of manner adverbs _including_ clause-initial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I think by "proverb" you mean "adverb?" And secondly, to answer to your question, no -- those three sentences (on their own) are equivalent, at least to my ear.

Comment: 1. Please, look at the edited question. 2. Do exist some context where they have different meaning?

Comment: I think the two sentences are equivalent, i.e. there's no difference in meaning (in any context I can think of).

Comment: But you have said the same about the end and middle placement, too. And in the post cited is clearly seen, that they are significantly different.

Comment: The cited post is pretty interesting, and l need to give it more thought. However, the two (three) sentences you mentioned are equivalent. I will need to think more about a general answer.